# press on UIImage and fire a method

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I have a UIImage and I want to be able to press the UIImage and have it animate. Is this possible to be able to press on the UIImage? 
THanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could replace your UIImageView with a UIButton and load the image into that, you can then respond to the button press events.

Answer (score 4):

No.  UIImage is a model object, and knows nothing about user interface/interaction.

You *can* create a UIImageView that displays the image.  Then add a UITapGestureRecognizer (and setUserInteractionEnabled:YES on the UIImageView!).  Then animate the UIImageView in the handler method.

Answer (score 0):

In case if you don't want create a Tap Gesture Recognizer,you can use the following code snippet

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGPoint pt= [[touches anyObject] locationInView:imageView];
    if ([imageView pointInside:pt withEvent:event]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Inside");
        //Fire your method here.
    }
}
```

You do not have make the UIImageview's userInteraction enabled for this method.